# VPN over VPN using Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have a OpenVPN configuration file for TryHackMe that I need to connect to. However, I also need to connect to another OpenVPN Access Server hosted on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance. Is there a way that I can first connect to the EC2 instance & then do some port forwarding on the instance to redirect all traffic from my computer to TryHackMe ? Basically I need all my requests to go through EC2 instance to TryHackMe